# react-leaflet Layer Action for Timestamp selection and Center Map such as available in Ellipsis Drive Layers View

Tags: react-leaflet

I want to know how can we have component in react-leaflet like a Layer Action for Timestamp selection with or without range and Center Map such as available in Ellipsis Drive Layers View:

[Example of component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Udd.png)

I tried to go through documentations provided by Ellipsis Drive for it's plugins and also react-leaflet documentations and examples.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please enjoy the read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.